# Laravel ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error with this code

```
<?php foreach(App\Campaign::all() as $campaign) { ?>
    <?php
        $category_id =  $campaign->category->id;
        $emailTemplates = App\EmailTemplate::where('category_id', $category_id);
        $lastEmailNumber = $emailTemplates->latest()->first()->number;
        $currentEmailNumber = $campaign->emails->last()->number;
    ?>

    <?php for ($i = $currentEmailNumber + 1; $i < $lastEmailNumber; $i++) { ?>
        <?php $pass = $emailTemplates->where("number", $i)->first()->password; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I know that for this time `$currentEmailNumber = 0` and `$lastEmailNumber = 14`
The problem is coming from the variable `$i` on line 9. If instead of using $i, I use any number from 1 to 14 it does not get any errors. For example:

```
<?php $pass = $emailTemplates->where("number", 10)->first()->password; ?>
```

But if I display only `$i`, without all that sentence it displays correctly.
Maybe it is cast problem.

Comment: You are getting trying to get property of non object which means you are trying to get a property from an object which is not exist and I highly doubt this error comes from `$i` 

My guess is $campaign makes the error. Can you post these two ?
`dd($emailTemplates->latest()->first()->number);`
`dd($$campaign->emails->last()->number);`

Comment: It gets 14 and 0. What is weird is that if I put 1 and 14 en the loop.
`for ($i = 0 + 1; $i < 14; $i++)`
It does not work with the $i on `<?php $pass = $emailTemplates->where("number", $i)->first()->password; ?>` But it works If I put for example `<?php $pass = $emailTemplates->where("number", 14)->first()->password; ?>` or any number between 1 and 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Changed this:

```
<?php $pass = $emailTemplates->where("number", $i)->first()->password; ?>
```

For this:

```
<?php $pass = App\EmailTemplate::where('category_id', $category_id)->where("number", $i)->first()->password; ?>
```

I do not know why althought.